# How to retrieve and display Eloquent relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, filter, view, fetch

#### What I'm trying to accomplish:

Retrieve all `App\Post` models related to the authenticated user and display them in the view.

---

#### Errors I'm receiving:

`Undefined variable:` and `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance` when clicking on the `<a name="posts">` tag.

---

#### What I've been trying:

**PagesController** :

```
 public function show($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('pages.index', compact('user'));
}
```

**Index** :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Welcome to notesite!</h1>
    
        <a href="/notes/show/{{ Auth::user()->id }}" name="posts">Show your posts</a>

    
@endsection
```

**Routes** :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/pages/index', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/pages/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/pages/services', 'PagesController@services');

Route::get('/notes/index', 'NotesController@index');
Route::get('/notes/show/{user}', 'NotesController@show');
Auth::routes();
    
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

---

Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: I trimmed it to just show the important code, that's all

Comment: You can just simply use `auth()->user()->id`

Comment: Yes! I used an almost identical piece of code you can see at the bottom of my post. Thank you, it works!

Comment: you can also use only Auth::id()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I'd recommend you reading up on [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships), especially the part about [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) if you plan on dealing with a lot of records.

You could do something like the following:

**User Model**

```
// Add this bit to your existing model to define the relationship 
// ( assuming that 1 user can have many different posts )

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

**Post Model**

```
// By default, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column,
// noted here as user_id

protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'user_id'];
```

**PostController**

```
public function show() {
    $posts = App\User::find(Auth::id())->posts; // Fetch the authenticated users posts

    return view('show-posts', compact('posts') ); // Pass them back to the view
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::view('/pages/index', 'index');
Route::get('/posts/show', 'PostController@show');
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<a href="/posts/show">Show user-specific posts!</a>
```

**show-posts.blade.php**

```
@foreach( $posts as $post )
    {{ $post->body }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it! Will try it out!